# How to update row information with new list in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

```
   Number  Country Region
0    5381   London   Asia
1    7357  Romania     EU
```

I want to change Region information. For example for Romania, Milan, Spain, Italy it will change to EU. likewise for London and UK it will change to United Kingdom.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What have you tried so far? How are you storing this data? What are you doing to choose the changes - do you have a list of the changes you need to make?

Comment: df.loc[df['Country'] == 'Italy', ['Region']] = 'Pasta' i tried this but it’s changing only one record i want to change multiple records for example {'Italy','Spain','Milan'  :   'EU'} so for this 3 countries it will change to EU, {'London','xyz'  : 'United Kingdom '} like this i want to change information

Answer (score 0):

[pandas.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) sounds like the a good fit for this opperation.

```
import pandas as pd

columns_list = ['Number', 'Country', 'Region']

data_list = [
    [5381, 'London', 'Asia'],
    [7357, 'Romania', 'EU'],
    [1234, 'Italy', 'EU'],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_list, columns=columns_list)

region_update_dict = {
    'London': 'United Kingdom',
    'Italy': 'Pasta Land'
}


def region_update_lambda(row):
    row_country = row['Country']
    row_region = row['Region']
    try:
        updated_region = region_update_dict[row_country]
    except KeyError:
        updated_region = row_region
    return updated_region


df['New Region'] = df.apply(lambda row: region_update_lambda(row), axis=1)
print(df)
#    Number  Country Region      New Region
# 0    5381   London   Asia  United Kingdom
# 1    7357  Romania     EU              EU
# 2    1234    Italy     EU      Pasta Land
```